# Banner gets cut off when zoomed in or on low resolution (mobile device)

Tags: php, html, css, web, banner

This problem is actually on a populated website as well, www.godaddy.com. When you zoom in or if you're on a mobile device, the right of the banner is cut off. If you're on a computer and you're viewing the page full sized, there is no problem. My website is: www.clinkstr.tk
Here's the CSS code:

```
#pageTop {
    background:#006DD9;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 0;
}
```

Some f the code is probably unnecessary because of me repeatedly trying different things to fix it.
Also, when you zoom in, the website seems to get a little bit messed up and things start to go out of place like the light gray background (which is suppose to be centered). Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters `#pageTopWrap` is gonna need `max-width: 100%` or that `width: 1100px;` declaration is gonna make it overflow every time.

In fact, you've got widths declared in inflexible pixels for a ton of things. `width` is very heavy-handed.  You'll have to override each with `max-width` declarations.  That iframe is gonna cause some headaches too.  If you don't mind dealing with things getting cut off, you could put `overflow:hidden;` on `#pageMiddle`, which will force that element to hide anything that overflows it (pretty straight-forward).

Comment: Well, that fixes one problem. Now there are 2 more. Both the footer and the header get cut off when you're zooming in, however, it actually shows up correctly on my phone now.

Comment: How do I exactly make the banner go all the way across the the screen though? When I zoom in and scroll to the right, the banner AND the footer both won't extend all the way. That's the only thing that I need to fix right now.

Comment: @CaptainDuude I mean, you could put `overflow:hidden;` on `#pageTop` and `#pageBottom`, too, but wrestling with fixed widths like this is always rough, and `overflow:hidden;` is a quick fix and not a real solution.  Try putting your HTML and CSS into a fiddle at [jsfiddle.net](http://http://jsfiddle.net) and post the link and I'll try to help you more through that.

Comment: Then is there an alternative to fixed widths?

Comment: Using wrapping containers can help, as [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) does. That way there's only one element with a set width and others can use percentages, which will flex. In fact, I recommend stealing techniques from Bootstrap's CSS; solid styles can teach you a lot. You can also look into [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to help with adjusting things for different sizes.